# Source SharePoint still accessible after Migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, migration

I was wondering after migration of SharePoint from tenant to tenant, will the old/source SharePoint sites still be accessible?

Comment: Are you doing copy migration content from old tenant to new tenant? What process are you following for migration? Any links you are following?

Comment: Yes copying the content.

Comment: If only copying the content from old tenant to new tenant, old SharePoint site should be accessible.

Comment: Which needs to be deactivated manually right ?

Comment: Yes, correct. you can lock sites if you want, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-lock-status. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: This will help on this note, Thank you !

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing content migration from one SharePoint tenant to another SharePoint tenant,

Your old/source SharePoint online sites will be accessible to users in your tenant.

If you want to restrict the access to old/source SharePoint sites, you can lock the SharePoint sites or redirect users to new SharePoint sites.

Follow this Microsoft official documentation for same: [Lock and unlock sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-lock-status)